# Chrome Extension - Not submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't get my form on my Chrome Extension to submit:

This is the `main.js` file:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action (in this case, submitting the form)
        $('#status').hide();
        $.post(
            'http://www.domain.com/?i=ajax', 
            $('form').serialize(),
            function (data) {
                proccessData(data);
            }
        );
        return false;    
    });
});

function proccessData (data) {
    alert("Submitted!");
    if(data=='success'){
        $('form').hide();           
        $('#status').addClass('noti success').html('<p>Your reply has been added.</p>').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#status').removeClass().addClass('noti error').html('<p>'+data+'</p>').fadeIn();
    }
}
```

And this is my `popup.html` file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="main.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="http://www.domain.com/?i=ajax">
<label for="url">Test</label>
<input id="urlname" name="url" type="text" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form> 
<div id="status"></div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "My App",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/19x19.png",
            "38": "icons/38x38.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Quick Dashboard - domain Addon",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
       "http://www.domain.com/"
     ]
}
```

Nothing happens when I submit the form.. I dont see no errors in the development tools either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your netowrk tab in the developer tools? See here https://i.stack.imgur.com/duC0g.png. It should tell you that status of your request. For my code I used http://requestb.in/ to make a `POST` request. See if this helps?

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://www.domain.com/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        i : "ajax"
    }
});

request.done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```